# NG2 e2e tests hang due to webpack creating a websocket

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-e2e

I'm assuming it's webpack's live-reload feature that is creating the web socket.  However, when running the e2e tests, they fail because NG2 never complete's its loading.  So far a work around is...

```
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);

    browser.wait(...)
```

..but that sucks.  What I'd like to do is run the e2e's against a prod build, assuming it wouldn't have the live-reload feature.  I've tried adding the `--prod` flag to `ng e2e`, and experimented with a few others but still the socket gets created.

Answer (score 0):

LOL, I missed this the first time around. There's a `--live-reload false` flag for `ng e2e` and it actually stops socketjs from loading.  Unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem.  Angular still times out.